# Making a Java Dual-exported server daemon

Tags: java, rmi

I have the following server class that export himself for JRMP and IIOP:

```
public class FooServer implements RemoteInt{
    FooServer(){
        UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this);
        PortableRemoteObject.exportObject(this);
    }

    public boolean remoteMethod() throws RemoteException{
        // some stuff
        return false;
    }
}
```

and the following setup class which creates the server and register it to a running register:

```
public class Setup{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        RemoteInt serv = new FooServer();
        Naming.rebind("//localhost/server", this);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when Setup finishes its job, it waits for the FooServer to terminate. Instead I would like to exit from Setup class, leaving the FooServer running.
How can I do?

Comment: Are you indicating that one of the `exportObject(this)` calls doesn't ever return (i.e. because it is blocking waiting for input on a socket), or that `main` exits but the application continues to run?

Comment: Like EJP said, the main exits but the application continues to run because there are thread listening for connections.

Comment: "I would like to exit from Setup class."  As described, that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Yes, but I mean "I would like to exit from this VM" actually, and keep the server running as a daemon.

Comment: That's just not possible. The server is hosted in the VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The remote object is exported from the current JVM and it keeps it running until you unexport it. Note that the main() method does exit, but the RMI/JRMP and RMi/IIOP listening threads are still running so the JVM doesn't exit.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for a way to do it, maybe using in some way the Thread.setDaemon(bool) method or something else.

Comment: @Alessio What part of "you can't" didn't you understand? If the JVM exits the remote objects will cease to exist. They need the JVM to run in. You seem to think they suddenly exist in a parallel universe. They don't.

Comment: I was thinking something like spawning a new JVM for the server from the Setup.

Comment: @Alessio You still don't seem to understand. Creating the remote objects occurs in the current JVM, and exporting them also occurs from the current JVM. When the current JVM exits, so do the exported objects. What JVM were you expecting them to run in exactly? Because there isn't one, other than the one they were exported from.

Comment: @Alessio And of course you can spawn a new JVM any way you like. Windows START command and Unix '&' come to mind. You don't need to write any Java code at all. However the Java code *in the spawned JVM* will need to do what your present Setup code does.